# How to fetch non-translated data in this given scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose in my application, I am inserting a few data(here questions) in a specific table in SQL SERVER.

```
 -------------------------------------------
               TBL_QUESTIONS
   -------------------------------------------
    question_id|subj_code_id|question_text
    -----------|------------|------------------
        1      |    1       | A basic question
    -----------|------------|------------------
        2      |    1       | Another Question...
    -----------|------------|-------------------
        3      |    1       | Again a question
```

Now anything that I entered in this table has a culture of en-US.

Currently, I have the following cultures.

```
 -------------------------------
     TBL_LANG_CULTURE
   -------------------------------
    lang_id|lang_name|culture_name
    -------|---------|-------------
       1   | English |  en-US
       2   | Hindi   |  hi-IN
       3   | French  |  fr-FR
```

Now there is another table which is storing translated part of those questions...

```
----------------------------------------
         TBL_TRANSLATED_QUESTINS
---------------------------------------
question_id| lang_culture|question_text
-----------|-------------|---------------
     1     |   hi-In     | एक बुनियादी सवाल
-----------|-------------|----------------
     2     |   hi-In     | एक और सवाल
-----------|-------------|----------------
     2     |   fr-FR     |  Une autre question
```

Now, If I want to display how many questions are there which is not translated yet in French. Then the output should look like this,

```
question_id| English_TEXT      | TRANSLATED_TEXT
-----------|-------------------|-----------------
    1      |  A basic question |            
-----------|-------------------|-----------------
    3      | Again a question  |
```

And now, If I want to display how many questions are there which is not translated yet in Hindi. Then the output should look like this,

```
question_id| English_TEXT      | TRANSLATED_TEXT
-----------|-------------------|-----------------
    3      | Again a question  |
```

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_QUESTIONS A 
LEFT JOIN TBL_TRANSLATED_QUESTINS B
    ON A.question_id = B.question_id
    AND lang_culture = 'fr-FR' -- To check French
WHERE B.question_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This result can be achieved by using join and then filter. Something like below might help you -

```
SELECT TQ.question_id, TQ.question_text, TTQ.question_text
FROM TBL_QUESTIONS TQ
LEFT JOIN (SELECT question_id, lang_culture, question_text
           FROM TBL_TRANSLATED_QUESTINS TT2
           WHERE TTQ.question_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT question_id
                                     FROM TBL_LANG_CULTURE TLC
                                     INNER JOIN TBL_TRANSLATED_QUESTINS TTQ ON TLC.culture_name = TTQ.lang_culture
                                     WHERE lang_name = 'French')) ON TQ.question_id = TTQ.question_id
WHERE TQ.question_id IS NULL
```

I have not tried it yet, but this should work for you.